# Replacing two characters with two different characters using regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to replace two different characters with two other different characters using regex in python in one operation. For example: The word is "a/c stuff" and i want to transform this into "ac_stuff" using regex in one regex.sub() line.
I searched here, but find ways to solve this using replace function, but i am looking to do this using regex in one line.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DeepSpace OP already has two problems

Comment: @anubhava talk about overfitting..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically possible, but not pretty to do this in one line using `re.sub`

```
re.sub("[/ ]", (lambda match: '' if match.group(0) == '/' else '_'), "a/c stuff")
```

Much nicer (and faster) way using `str.translate`

```
"a/c stuff".translate(str.maketrans({'/': None, ' ': '_'}))
```

or

```
"a/c stuff".translate(str.maketrans(' ', '_', '/'))
```

Probably the most readable way is through `str.replace`, though this doesn't scale well to many replacements.

```
"a/c stuff".replace('/', '').replace(' ', '_')
```

Comment: Any advantage for preferring `None` over `''`?

Comment: That's what `str.maketrans` does for the three argument version, which is how I usually use `translate`.  Looks like either works.

Comment: Anyway I never really understood why we can't pass a dict directly to `translate`

Comment: @DeepSpace It can, but it has to be a translation table.  `"a/c stuff".translate({32: 95, 47: None})` works just fine.

Comment: You could add list comprehension as well:    "".join([i.replace("/","").replace(" ","_") for i in "a/c stuff"])